# Using readline() in python 3.4

Tags: python, readline, python-3.4

I am searching for a keyword say "My system"
So the readline will search for that keyword and copy the paragraph in which this keyword is present.
I need to add '#" symbol before every line of the paragraph being printed.
The code given below gives me just the first line added with "#".

```
z=open("ABC.txt","r")
for line in z.readlines():
    if "My system" in line:
        w.write('{}{}'.format('\n"#"',(line)))
```

How can i add "#" before every line of that particular paragraph.
Please help

Comment: How do you identify a paragraph?

Comment: whenever it encounters continuous 3 white spaces , a paragraph is identified, basically i am testing this code on a file with just 1 sample paragraph written.

Comment: Perhaps include a small sample file with more than one paragraph. Then show us the Python code you use to identify a paragraph in it.

Comment: You have to keep track where a pragraph starts and where it ends and add the `#` for every line in between. Something like `inside=False;for line in z:if start_paragraph(line):inside=True;elif end_paragraph(line):inside=False;w.write(('#' if inside else '') + line)` however you should provided a *clear* definition of what you consider a paragraph (and I have no idea what `My system` has to do with commenting paragraphs...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a buffer (e.g. a `list`) of lines that are part of the "current" paragraph as you are iterating through the lines. Set a flag when you find your keyword, and when you reach the next paragraph whitespace, print all of the buffered paragraph lines with or without your `#` symbol. Otherwise, by the time you've matched the keyword the previous lines are "done" from your loop's perspective.

Comment: thnx @Jason S, but i am not sure as to how can i manipulate the above to carry on with these steps...can u help with that?